# pushViewController error

Tags: xcode

i have xcode 3.3
I have a problem in pushViewController
When you run error appears also in the picture
http://s11.postimage.org/5wjkhg303/Screen_Shot_2012_07_29_at_9_39_43_PM.png

Answer (score 1):

Make sure DetailViewControllerTow.xib is part of your project. The exception "Could not load NIB in bundle" is telling you that it could not be found.

Comment: i dont have DetailViewControllerTow.xib file i have a Storyboard ViewController linked with DetailViewControllerTow class

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a xib for your ViewController which isn't unusual in Storyboard apps. My suggestion would be that you do this in storyboard instead!